# close print preview button in excel does not close first time

Tags: excel, vba, printing, office365, ribbonx

```
    Sub btnPrintInternalList()
    Dim fullrange As String
    SetPrintAreaRange
    Sheets("Internal List").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    On Error Resume Next
    RLR_I_L = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
    RLC_I_L = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
       
    fullrange = Cells(Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Address
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$T$" & RLR_I_L
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, preview:=True, Collate:=False
    
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:" & fullrange
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work without running your VBA code?

Comment: No, it is required to set PrintArea dynamically, records on the sheet are dynamic.

Comment: Sounds like this is a product issue, not related to the code, right?

Comment: yes, itr seems like that.

Comment: I'd suggest opening a support case with MS then.